# MVC - Can I display Title and Massage on 1 View by 2 different Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm new to MVC and also new to Stackoverflow. I'm not working with any Database but I simply want to display Title and Massage on 1 View by 2 different Controllers. I want in my Index.cshtml file the `@ViewBag.Title` display from HomeController.cs file and the `@ViewBag.Massage` display from `OtherController.cs` file. How can I do this and how to reference or attach `OtherController.cs` to `Index.cshtml`? Please don't tell me that I'm asking for something like how to attach stylesheet to html but it's not possible with MVC.

If it's really not possible then please tell me how to do this by partial views with having a _Layout.cshtml file. Because I don't want to write too much in my View Files.

Thank You in Advance!

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home",
                                action = "Index",
                                id = UrlParameter.Optional
                              }
               );
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "";
            return View();
        }
```

**OtherController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Massage = "";
            return View();
        }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

<p>@ViewBag.Massage</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index action method will be same in home controller but in Other controller you should return partial view .

```
   public ActionResult PartialIndex()
    {
        ViewBag.Massage = "Message from Partial View";
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Partial view

```
 <p>@ViewBag.Massage</p>
```

In main View you can call this.

```
  <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
  <h2>@{Html.RenderAction("IndexPartial");}</h2>
```

Comment: akhlesh - But where is @ViewBag.Massage main View?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you can but if you would do it the proper way then you would make 2 different views with the specific content and then each `ActionResult` refers to a view. In other words the best way of doing it is not the way you are trying to do it.

Comment: Should I use partial view or something for this?

Comment: Partial View is usually for something you want to use again and again. E.g. a login or a search bar. The way I would do it is to create 2 views and the have the same content in both of them. It is the best practise as the "pages" will be complex and difficult to understand when site becomes larger.

Comment: "In other words the best way of doing it is not the way you are trying to do it." Hey! should not you suggest me the best way Instead of saying this.

Comment: Highace2 - Your answer is helpful, even if i can't Vote up your ans cause of my reputation points or something. :)

Comment: @MaryMelody Great :-)